Can you make an empty type in typescript?
Imagine I want to do
type empty = (no elements)

You can try
type empty = {}

but it doesn't work as {} is now an element of empty.
Ok, then how about this:
type empty = null

Hmm? No, now null is an element of empty...
Last resort,
type empty;

But then it causes an error (at least for TS playground)! Is there any way to make an empty type? (Just because it may be useless doesn't mean it's fun!)

Think of it like the False type in Lean.

what about never?

@DanielA.White Oh.

What exactly do you mean by an empty type? the notation you use suggest an empty array, like an array with length 0. Or you mean a type that cannot contain anyting?

@DanielCruz Yes to the type with nothing

can ((p: empty) => string) ever produce a string?
